# How to add text to my UINavigationBar?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationbar

I've set the color of my `UINavigationBar` in my `AppDelegate` like so:

`[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBarTintColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:40/255.0f green:167/255.0f blue:255/255.0f alpha:1.0f]];`

How can I now add text that will be overlaid on this `UINavigationBar`?

Comment: You mean like the title text?

Comment: @Ron Yeah. I understand it's probably a stupid question, but I just can't seem to figure it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a viewcontroller you can write a following code in viewdidload

```
self.navigationItem.title = @"The title";
```

Answer (score 0):

For title of the UINavigationBar just write:

```
self.title = @"Your Title";
```

in your **viewDidLoad** method. It is the most easiest and quickest way for giving the title to the navigation bar.